# Merge operation without exception but with no impact on the database Glassfish 4.1 JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entitymanager, glassfish-4.1

I got a table with a string field and try to update this field and the merge the update to the database via EntityManager. This is done and without exceptio but I see no effect on the database and ran out of ideas what's up there. Hope somebody has an idea. In the below exampl `match != null` and with both print statements I get the expected value written to my log. But the merge within the transaction has no impact on the database even though the commit terminated.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public String mymethod(){
        ...
        match.setPwdResetId(rs);
        System.out.println("reset it is now "+match.getPwdResetId());
        try{
            ut.begin();
            emf.createEntityManager().merge(match);
            ut.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            FacesMessage m2 = new FacesMessage("Values could not be saved. ");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("ResetForm", m2);
            System.out.println("exceptio persisting "+e);
            return "message.jsf";
        }  
        System.out.println("reset it is now2 "+match.getPwdResetId());
```

Comment: can you detach the entity and then merge it?

Comment: Yes! How did u know?  After the detach I could even merge and now see it in the database. Would love to know the reasons and your thinking to learn. Thanks a lot

Comment: i added an answer to accept it along with the merge part of the jpa specification and a link to the whole specification pdf. have fun reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please detach the entity and try again.
You can read more at the jpa 2 specification. I post a sample for the merge operation:

> The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a    pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new 
>     managed copy X' of X is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is    created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity
>     instance X'.
> - If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will    be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will
>     fail).
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,    however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by
>     relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with
>     the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.
> - For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the    cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL, Y is merged
>     recursively as Y'. For all such Y referenced by X, X' is set to
>     reference Y'. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as 
>     X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity    Y, where cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL is not specified, then
>     navigation of the same association from X' yields a reference to a
>     managed object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.
>
> The persistence provider must not merge fields marked LAZY that have
>   not been fetched: it must ignore such fields when merging. Any Version
>   columns used by the entity must be checked by the persistence runtime
>   implementation during the merge operation and/or at flush or commit
>   time. In the absence of Version columns there is no additional version
>   checking done by the persistence provider runtime during the merge
>   operation.

you can find the whole pdf [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: Thanks. I don't really get that. What's the reason that a managed entity is ignored by merged? Is merge the wrong command for an SQL level update query? Seems odd that the proper way is detaching and then merging or am I not getting the concept?